# Creo que tengo un error en el showResultado

Tags: java, android-studio

me podrían ayudar, estoy haciendo una calculadora en android studio con JAVA, para las pruebas que he realizado, tengo 2 variables (numero1, numero2), cuando presiono la tecla sumar, el primer valor se me almacena en la variable (numero1), pero cuando digito otro numero (para sumar numero1 y numero2, y le doy en el botón igual, aparece que mi variable num1 está vacía.

agradezco la ayuda

[image: prueba]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado de manera rápida de esta forma, creando una variable donde almacene lo guardado en numero1, y esa variable la operé en

```
public void showResultado(View view) {
        System.out.println("el numero 1 en igual es: "+numeroalmacenado);
        numero2 = Float.parseFloat(tvResultado.getText().toString());

        if(operacion.equals("+")){
            float resultado = numeroalmacenado + numero2;
            tvResultado.setText(resultado+"" );
        }
```

[image: solución]